# Given direction cosines of two vectors. How to find the normal based on right hand rule

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to find mathematically/programmatically (not by putting thumb and fingers) how to find the normal of a plane according to the Right-hand rule (RHR). For RHR, should it be axb or bxa.

a,b are defined by their direction cosines l,m,n. a(l1,m1,n1) b(l2,m2,n2)

I need to perform this operation as part of an algorithm. Everywhere on the web, they put a picture with thumb and fingers, but the code doesn't understand the picture :-)

A couple of websites suggested to calculate the angle between the two vectors. If it is obtuse then use bxa. But given cosines of 2 vectors (a(l1,m1n1) and b(l2,m2n2) Angle between them would be = l1xl2+m1m2+n1n2. whether we find angle between a and or b and a. the value will be the same according to the formula.

My vectors are always perpendicular to each other. Angle always 90.

No thumb pictures, please :-) there are more than enough on the web...
A mathematical formula would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Given two vectors, their cross product is normal to both and follows the RHR convention.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But I'm not looking general definition of cross product. I need the specific mathematical formula to determine the correct normal of the two normals according to the RHR for the given two vectors specified by their direction cosines.